# Dynamic form elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reset

I'm building a simple dynamic form using jQuery's '.live()' event handler.

Although the form expands and contracts as required, the forms javascript '.reset' method only partially works.

To clarify, when either of the first two radio buttons are selected (in tier 1) the reset method should de-select any tier 2 options, however this only works with the first tier 2 form (tier2Foo1), and not the second (tier2Foo2).

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Build a Bin</title>
<style type="text/css">
#first {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
}
#hideFoo {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 250px;
    display: none;
}
#hideFoo2 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    display: none;
}
#first, #hideFoo, #hideFoo2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 350px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
}
.fieldContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0 10px 0;
}
.imageContainer {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid #666 1px;
}



</style>
<script src="javascript/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //TIER ONE Options
    $(document).ready(function () {             
        $('#Foo1').live('click', function() {
            $('#hideFoo').show(500);
            $('#hideFoo2').hide(500);
        });
        $('#Foo2').live('click', function() {
            $('#hideFoo2').show(500);
            $('#hideFoo').hide(500);
        });
        //uncheck and hide form element
        //tier 1 reset for tier 2
        $('#Foo1, #Foo2').live('click', function(){
            $('#tier2Foo1, #tier2Foo2')[0].reset();
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ////////////// Basic form containing two options \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ -->
<div id="first">
  <form id="tier1" action="#">
    <div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" alt=" " /></div>
    <p>Foo 1</p>
      <input type="radio" name="example" value="Foo1" id="Foo1" />
      <label for="Foo1">Foo 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" alt=" " /></div>
    <p>Foo 2</p>
      <input type="radio" name="example" value="Foo2" id="Foo2" />
      <label for="Foo2">Foo 2</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- ////////////// tier 2 for Foo1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ -->
<div id="hideFoo">
  <form id="tier2Foo1" action="#">
    <div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" alt=" " /></div>
    <p>The complete EcoSort Recycling System.</p>
      <input type="radio" name="example1" id="Foo1Opt1" />
      <label for="Foo1Opt1">Foo One Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldContainer">
    <div class="imageContainer"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" alt=" " /></div>
    <p>The complete EcoSort Recycling System.</p>
      <input type="radio" name="example1" id="Foo1Opt2" />
      <label for="Foo1Opt2">Foo One Option 2</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- ////////////// tier 2 for Foo2 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ -->
<div id="hideFoo2">
  <form id="tier2Foo2" action="#">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="example2" id="Foo2Opt1" />
      <label for="Foo2Opt1">Foo Two Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="example2" id="Foo2Opt2" />
      <label for="Foo2Opt2">Foo Two Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="example2" id="Foo2Opt3" />
      <label for="Foo2Opt3">Foo Two Option 3</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#tier2Foo1, #tier2Foo2')[0].reset();` only selects the zeroth form of the collection, so you are only applying `.reset` to one form.  This is pretty simple to fix:

```
$('#tier2Foo1, #tier2Foo2').each(function () { this.reset(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ruLdA/

---

By the way, `.live` was removed in jQuery 1.9.  Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score -1):

Haven't really tried. But in your code, it seems you are selecting only first one, so the second isn't reset.

```
 $('#tier2Foo1, #tier2Foo2')[0].reset();
```

Try removing `[0]`.

Comment: `.reset` is not a jQuery collection method, so that won't work.